# SQL Server date compare ignores year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am running a query on SQL Server 2005 to look up records within a date range. The `WHERE` clause looks like this:

```
WHERE (CONVERT(NVARCHAR, fldPublishedDate, 101) >= '" & toDate & 
   "' AND CONVERT(NVARCHAR, fldPublishedDate, 101) <= '" & fromDate & "')"
```

`toDate` and `fromDate` are entered like this `04/01/2005` and `04/30/2005`.

The results I am getting are definitely all between 1st and 30th of April but from various years, ranging from 2005 (when data collection started) to 2012. It looks like the year is simply ignored from the comparison. Am I missing something here?

Thank you for taking your time to read this.

Comment: Use parameters to prevent sql-injection and pass dates instead of strings.

Comment: Thank you everybody who answered. I know about injection risk but this is more of an internal tool, so I am not too worried about it.  Plus this was developed by somebody else and I was just trying to fix it. I don't even have access to SQL Server at this point, only the code.

Comment: Also, I don't know what was wrong with me and I didn't notice convert to nvarchar, obviously, that was the issue.  I was more interested to find out why it was working for month and date but not the year. Weird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you converting to a string? Of course this doesn't work as expected. You're saying:

```
IF '12/02/2010' > '09/12/2012'
```

Which of course yields true. You should be saying:

```
WHERE fldPublishedDate >= '20050401'
  AND fldPublishedDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '20050430');
```

You don't need to convert the column to a date only if you're only comparing date ranges. Most importantly you should be passing in dates in an unambiguous format that is immune from regional and language settings (e.g. `YYYYMMDD`). 101 isn't a safe style because what month is 04/06/2012 for people in England? That's June, not April. I suspect you should be formatting these dates better in your (classic ASP?) code, or passing in proper datetime data types from whatever language you're using. Finally, don't use NVARCHAR without length:

- [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: +1 couldn't have said it better - compare dates **as dates** and not as string :-)

Answer (score 2):

if `fldPublishedDate` is a date in your SQL server then why convert it to a `nvarchar` to do the comparison.  You can convert your `toDate` and `fromDate` to a datetime and do the comparison

```
declare @toDate nvarchar(50)
declare @fromDate nvarchar(50)

set @toDate  = '04/01/2005'
set @fromDate  = '04/30/2005'

select cast(@toDate as datetime), cast(@fromDate as datetime)

results:
ToDate                      FromDate
2005-04-01 00:00:00.000     2005-04-30 00:00:00.000
```

Then in your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE fldPublishedDate >= cast(@toDate as datetime)
 AND fldPublishedDate <= cast(@fromDate as datetime)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `fldPublishedDate` is a `datetime`, and that you want to compare on `date` only.

In SQL 2008, use the handy-dandy date type:

```
WHERE CONVERT(date, fldPublishedDate) >= CONVERT(date, '" & toDate & 
"' AND CONVERT(date, fldPublishedDate) <= CONVERT(date, '" & fromDate & "'"
```

In < SQL 2008, you can use the crazy syntax:

```
WHERE DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, fldPublishedDate), 0) >= CONVERT(datetime, '" & toDate & 
"' AND DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, fldPublishedDate), 0) <= CONVERT(datetime, '" & fromDate & "'"
```

Tehcnically, SQL will convert your `datetime` strings for you - so you could leave off the conversion of your values.

Also, you should readup on SQL Injection and parameters - it's easier to write, easier to read, and safer as well. Win, win, win.

Comment: The OP said that he's using SQL Server **2005** ... so we won't be able to use `DATE`. But you definitely have a very valid point on the SQL injection aspect

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do the conversion in both branches of the where clause? If the right-hand side is a date at midnight, what difference does it make if the left-hand side is that same date at midnight, or at 4:00 AM, or at 11:00 PM?